# How to check how many line intersects a intersecting point in same geometry

Tags: postgis, intersection, spatialite, linestring

I want to know that how many line intersects a point. In figure below it can be seen that 3 lines crosses a point. 2 red lines and 1 blue line. I want to know in the same geometry that many lines crosses an intersecting point.

I have tried it with st_intersection but its not working. Suppose if I have a point similar to that in the picture the query should return 3.

Is there any way in to check how many lines crosses an intersection point?

what I have tried is:

```
select Count(Distinct a2.id) as no_of_line_intersecting,
st_intersection(a1.geometry,a2.geometry) 
 as geom from Area a1,Area a1 where
ST_Touches(a1.geoemtry, a2.geometry)
```

But I am not getting the right results. Does somebody have any idea about this? I am using spatialite

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, what you have is one line table and you want each intersection points containing the number of line that intersect them ?
If so, I think the following query could do the job

```
WITH intersection_points AS (
         SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())::int as id,
                (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(l1.geom, l2.geom))).geom
         FROM line_table l1
           JOIN line_table l2
           ON ST_Intersects(l1.geom, l2.geom)
         )
SELECT i1.id, count(i2.id) as intersection_count
FROM intersection_points i1
  LEFT JOIN intersection_points i2
  ON ST_DWithin(i1.geom, i2.geom, 0.000001)
GROUP BY i1.id;
```

I'm using here ST_DWithin with a low tolerance to avoid any topological inconsistencies that could induce wrong results. You can use ST_Intersects if you want but I think this one is more robust.

The first table returns intersection points where the line table self-intersects. The - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())::int as id - assign for each entry the row number, cast it to integer type, to get an id for the newly created points.

I didn't test it so I don't know if it works properly, but I hope it does.

Comment: Cannot use ST_dump sorry I forgot to tell that I am using spatialite

Comment: Oh ok, I leave the answer if someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping by the intersection:

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT a.id),
           ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
    FROM <table> AS a,
         <table> AS b
    WHERE ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)
      AND a.id <> b.id
       OR ST_Crosses(a.geom, b.geom)
      AND a.id <> b.id
    GROUP BY ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)
```

With `ST_Touches` and `ST_Crosses` in `OR` condition this should return all points that intersect in a point geometry (since `ST_Intersects` could return all types of intersection geometries, e.g. if two lines overlap).
And: with those two `ST_Intersection` this is probably going to be awfully slow for large tables.

Comment: Yes its very slow and takes too much time and I have already tried this with ST_intersection grouping but does not give right results

Comment: Could you elaborate on the false results? I wouldn´t dare say this is final, but I haven´t come across a better solution than this or similar (based on your topology) yet; intersections are always coslty, and, in general, to count them all, you´ll have to find them all...

Comment: What do you mean by false results?. Actually my end target is to remove the blue line which is orthogonal to the point therefore, I want to know a point where more then two lines intersects

Comment: I mean you said grouping by _ST_Intersection_ would 'not give right results'...how are they wrong? If e.g. some intersections are missing, some lines may not touch (as @BFlat suggested). Knowing your data is crucial; if, for example, none of your lines actually cross each other (but do intersect in their endpoints ONLY), ST_Crosses would be useless. You can also use _group_concat(a.id)_ to get a string of intersecting ids per intersection instead of getting the actual _ST_Intersection_ in the _SELECT_ to slightly speed things up for very large tables (if that would be sufficient to know)?

Comment: Well I have made two queries instead of making one complex. The first query uses st_touches and ST_intersection to get the intersecting point and next query uses the point given by first query and checks how many ids are intersecting on this point using ST_intersects. Now its working

Comment: That's pretty much what @BFlat has suggested? Mind that it is possible that you get MultiPoints as result in certain cases (that's why he used _ST_Dump_). Actually I would be interested in your queries...if you don´t mind them being open for debate ,)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68693/discussion-between-thingumabob-and-mimetype).

Comment: I have written the queries in python using spatialite. If you want I can show them